# How to reinitialize a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.4

I have a class which uses a variable to create a string like so:

```
av = "Core/" + cuname + ">> "
```

In a specific method in the class, the `cuname` variable is changed. However, when prompted, the `av` variable is still going to use the previous value. Is there a way to "re-initialize" the variable so that it gets the new `cuname` value?

EDIT: By the way, I tried restating the variable, but it stays the same. (I think it is because the class is continually used using a loop)

Comment: Could you add some more code? Are you using an object or a class? How can you use cuname and not self.cuname, when cuname is a class member?

Comment: Could you please insert the relevant code within your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a class and `av` is a variable in it, make it a `property` of the class

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cuname = name

    @property
    def av(self):
        return "Core/" + self.cuname + ">> "


obj = MyClass("thefourtheye")
print(obj.av)
# Core/thefourtheye>> 
obj.cuname = "awesome"
print(obj.av)
# Core/awesome>>
```

`av` is a read-only property. So no matter how many times `cuname` changes, `av` will always give a string with the current `cuname` value. Since, you made `av` a property, it can still be used like a variable.

Comment: Thanks. I had to modify the loop a bit but this worked great.

Comment: You also could make cuname a property to use it as a variable like before.

Comment: @clemos24 Ya we could, but we don't actually know what the OP's problem is :(

Answer (score 2):

If you use a function instead of a variable, you always get the latest value:

```
class myclass():
    def av(self):
        return "Core/" + cuname + ">> "
```

So instead of using av, you now use self.av().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just re-execute the same statement:

```
av = "Core/" + cuname + ">> "
```

again.

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know why, but it still returns the old value.

Comment: I too cannot know, because I lack sufficient clairvoyance abilities. You were asked to add code in the question itself.

Comment: Doesn't matter now. I found a solution, but thanks for trying to help!